# Not Taking Screenshot of Activity while Dialog box is open

Tags: android, dialog, screenshot, android-dialog

I was developing an app to share screenshots when you've completed a game.
I made a sample app in which I take screenshots with the same code that I've used in my current activity. Unfortunately when I apply the same code to my game, which includes a dialog box, its not even taking the screenshot and its not storing it ether. Instead it opens the Share Intent.

Here is what I've done so far. Please tell me where the problem is or give me a suggestion how I can solve this problem.

Dialog box code

```
private void showWinDialod() {

    ImageView winshare = (ImageView) win_dialog.findViewById(R.id.winshare);

    winshare.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(activity);
            Log.e("Screenshot", "taken successfully");

            saveBitmap(bitmap);
            Log.e("Screenshot", "saved successfully");

             initShareIntent("image", "WOW You done it");
        }
    });

    win_dialog.show();
    win_dialog.getWindow().getDecorView()
            .setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
}
```

here is the code of `takeScreenShot(activity)`

```
private static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {
    View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
    Rect frame = new Rect();
    activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
    int statusBarHeight = frame.top;
    int width = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int height = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
            .getHeight();

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height
            - statusBarHeight);
    view.destroyDrawingCache();
    Log.e("Screenshot", "taken successfully");
    return b;

}
```

Here is `saveBitmap(bitmap)` Code

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        Log.e("Screenshot", "saved successfully");

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

and at the end `initShareIntent("image","WOW")`

```
private void initShareIntent(String type, String _text) {
    // optional //internal storage
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _text);
    shareIntent.putExtra(
            Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/screenshot.png"))); // optional//use this when you
                                            // want to send an image
    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
}

public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/screenshot.png");
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        Log.e("Screenshot", "saved successfully");

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

}
```

This Code is working totally fine when I'm not using a dialog box but it's not working when the dialog box is open.

Its Take the Screenshot but in storing i got this  exception

```
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):/storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:73)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at com.game.guessemoji.MainActivity.saveBitmap(MainActivity.java:5118)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at com.game.guessemoji.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:4323)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
07-24 18:06:41.846: E/GREC(21546):  ... 15 more

Comment: `Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(activity);`. What is `activity`?

Comment: `its not even taking the screenshot`. Well you execute some code. What does it return? What goes wrong? You log some things. What is logged?

Comment: First I remove the last part
second `Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(activity);`
activity is `Activity activity = (MainActivity) this; `
and in last its not even Showing the Log in Log cat but executing the function after log which is `initshareIntent` @greenapps

Comment: I don't understand what you said.`Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenShot(activity);
            Log.e("Screenshot", "taken successfully");`. That is wrong coding. You first should check if bitmap==null. Only then you know if it has been taken. If bitmapp== null then do not continue but display a Toast saying so. 
`

Comment: its capturing perfectly but in storing i got the exception check my updated question for exception detail i know its just a mess but please to to manage it @greenapps

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/screenshot.png`. Well there is the problem. Why did you not tell before? Now you have posted the code for void saveBit() twice. Why?. Make it a decent `boolean saveBitmap()`. So you can use the return value to not continue if saving fails. As to your problem: `EACCES (Permission denied)` Did you forget to request a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file?

Comment: `catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);`. As you had that code already I wonder why you did not report this log right away.

Comment: i really forgot to report this log in first place and yes i have this permission already in manifest file @greenapps

Comment: Please copy/paste that permission. Many people have typo's.

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` @greenapps

Answer (score 0):

The problem with dialog is its in another window and has another root view then your activity. Therefore it does not appear in your screenshot.
Try out this library: https://github.com/jraska/Falcon.
It takes screenshots of all active windows of application including dialogs and could figure out your problem.